# How can I create a Ratings Summary?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create the bar lines as below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create it with just a column, that has 5 rows as its children. Each row has the star count, the star icon, the progress bar and the percentage text as its children. In terms of how to implement the green progress bar with widgets, I would simply stack two Containers onto each other using the Stack widget. Controlling the width of the top Container, you can then control how much of the bar is filled with green. Seems very straightforward to me.

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple approach. I was hoping there was a package that I could you.

Comment: I highly doubt that there is one. Because what your trying to achieve is rather unique

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this based on the guidance from @TheUltimateOptimist. He is my solution, its pretty basic, but it works. Here is what it looks like and the code below.

[image]

```
import 'package:myapp/config/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ReviewChart extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReviewChart({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          chartRow(context, '5', 89),
          chartRow(context, '4', 8),
          chartRow(context, '3', 2),
          chartRow(context, '4', 1),
          chartRow(context, '1', 0),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget chartRow(BuildContext context, String label, int pct) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Text(label, style: AppTheme.bodyText1),
        SizedBox(width: 8),
        Icon(Icons.star, color: AppTheme.iconColor),
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(8, 0, 8, 0),
          child:
          Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppTheme.iconColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: Text(''),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * (pct/100) * 0.7,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppTheme.color3,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
                ),
                child: Text(''),
              ),
            ]

          ),
        ),
        Text('$pct%', style: AppTheme.bodyText1),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```